# send URL from one page to another using ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

I need to send URL from one page which contains a form, to another page to check whether the link exist in my database or not. so there are URLs with special characters such as '+' '%' and some part of the URL is html encoded, and some are not. so I cannot encode and send the URL to decode from the receiver page.

```
$('#searchbutton').click(function(){
    var url = $('#urltext').val();
    $('#datatodiv').load("searchlink.php?url="+url);
});
```

When I input the URL "http://www.example.com/ae2/STUDIO+CHANNEL+PRO/" which received at the searchurl.php page as "http://www.example.com/ae2/STUDIO CHANNEL PRO/" where the '+' is changed to empty space. There are cases in which encoded data such as "%20" etc used.

Comment: Changed the load request to GET in jquery, now its got working.
`$.get("searchurl.php", {url:url}, function(data){
    alert(data);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `encodeURI()` to encode a url:

```
var url = encodeURI($('#urltext').val());
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RoryMcCrossan/vSD6r/)

This will at least ensure that the URL values being sent have a consistent encoding.

Comment: @KrishnaRajK and/or `urldecode`, yes, depending on what you want to accomplish =)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use PHP functions -

```
base64_encode()
base64_decode()
```

Comment: I have to do it in the page while sending itself.